Compose multiplatform CI file
I'm working on a CI integration for Compose multiplatform (with Circle CI).
I want to build a debug build; it does not need to be production-ready.
My .yaml file looks like this:
version: 2.1

orbs:
  android: circleci/android@2.5.0

jobs:
  build-apps:
    executor:
      name: android/android-machine
      resource-class: large
      tag: default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ./gradlew assemble
      - store_artifacts:
          path: composeApp/build/outputs/
          destination: build-outputs

  build-ios:
    macos:
      xcode: "15.2.0"
    steps:
      - checkout
     
      - run: ./gradlew composeApp:iosArm64Binaries
      - store_artifacts:
          path: composeApp/build/bin/iosArm64
          destination: build-outputs
workflows:
  build-all:
    jobs:
      - build-apps
      - build-ios

The android build works correctly.
However for iOS it only creates a .dSYM file which is not good to install on a device. For that I need an IPA file.
When I'm checking examples I see that I need to run something like this:
- run:
          name: Install Gem dependencies
          command: |
            cd iosApp

However when I try to run this command I got an error message that Could not locate Gemfile.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!
bundle install
